# How to match the following pattern with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a regular exp as follows `(((\(?\+?1?\)?)\s?-?)?((\(?\d{3}\)?\s?-?\s?))?\s?\d{3}\s?-?\s?\d{4}){1}` it matches the numbers in this format  `xxx-xxx-xxxx` ; where x are digits from 0-9. How can I make it to match the numbers also with dots(.) for example `xxx.xxx.xxxx` and also to match with `xxx.xxx.xxx`

Answer (score 3):

**A simpler regex**

I would suggest simplifying the regex to this (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hP7oS5) of what matches and doesn't match):

```
^\d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{3,4}$
```

One benefit of this expression is that we ensure that the same delimiter `-` or `.` is used between the groups of digits. We do this by capturing the delimiter to group 1 using `([-.])`, then by referencing that capture later using `\1`.

**Explanation:**

```
^             # assert position at the beginning of the string
\d{3}         # match any digit from 0-9 (3 times)
(             # group and capture to \1
  [-.]        # match any character in the list: '-', '.'
)             # end of first capturing group
\d{3}         # any digit from 0-9 (3 times)
\1            # what was matched by group 1
\d{3,4}       # match any digit (0-9) (3 or 4 times)
$             # assert position at the end of the string (before an optional \n)
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's original regex, it seems they wanted to handle `+`, parentheses, and whitespace. But it is not mentioned as a requirement, and this wouldn't be hard to adjust as per the exact requirements anyway, so have a +1.

Comment: op wants 3 digits also at the last.

Comment: @AmalMurali Thank you. :) Yes, the `xxx.xxx.xxx` requirement clashes with the original regex... In such cases I tend to go with the data rather than the regex, but it may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With little modification it will be:

```
(((\(?\+?1?\)?)\s?[-.]?)?((\(?\d{3}\)?\s?[-.]?\s?))?\s?\d{3}\s?[-.]?\s?\d{3,4}){1}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Original one:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: IMO, a little modification is good, a little **simplification** is better.

Comment: @Stephan Yes, zx81 answer is way better within given OP's description. But I decided to keep original regex in case if OP didn't state the full problem.